# Integral of Squared Sum of Sine

Tags: integration, summation, symbolic-computation

Let's say we have the following function

$$ \int \left( \sum_{i = 1}^\infty a_i \sin(b_ix)\right)^2$$

Assuming that this series converges (it is actually a Fourier Series of the Lagrangian of the Wave Equation), how would we go about solving this? I know I need to move the integral inside of the sum, but the squared is making this difficult.

Added note: I can't find the tag for homework, but I don't need a full solution, simply how to get the integral inside of the sum.

Comment: Hint:$$2\sin b_ix\sin b_jx=\cos(b_i-b_j)x-\cos(b_i+b_j)x.$$

Comment: The homework tag [was burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag)…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\left(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty } a_j \sin (b_j x )\right)^2 dx =\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_j ^2 \int\sin^2 (b_j x ) dx+2\sum_{1\leq i<j<\infty}a_i a_j\int \sin (b_i x)\sin (b_j x) dx$$
under suitable assumptions concerning convergence of the above series.